# Guardar Impresión de Imagen - Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

¿Cómo puedo guardar la impresión de una imagen (banner) en google analytics?
Actualmente he logrado guardar el hover y click de la imagen de la siguiente forma:

```
onmouseover='ga("send","event","imagen","hover_img","desktop_mobile")';

onclick='ga("send","event","imagen","click_img","desktop_mobile")';
```

Pero necesitaría también guardar cuantas veces se imprimió.

Answer (score 0):

Si por impresión entendemos una página vista, evento natural de GA, entonces puedes enviar con el sistema **onmouseover**.

Sin embargo utilizando el sistema de visualización de un elemento  desde GTM es más sencillo, ya que puedes utilizar una escala de umbrales de visualización del elemento (ej. 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%) y dispara cualquier evento a cualquiera de las etiquetas.